# How to display text/image in the upload area of primefaces fileUpload?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I'm displaying text/image in the upload area to have Upload here Text/image, When user uplaod file or drop file that should disappear.

Tried the following with Primefaces 6.2 and JSF 2.2 but the output is not what should be achieved.

```
<h:form> 
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadView.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="true"
              update="messages" sizeLimit="100000" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" />
<p:outputLabel style="display:block; background: white;text-align:center">Drop here</p:outputLabel>
    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />          
</h:form>
```

Any possibility to have an image or text showing that upload files here in the upload area and then disappear when user upload files?

Comment: have you tried label or uploadLabel attribute?

Comment: @blablabla uploadLabel attribute change text of Upload button, I need the uplaod area to display text and disappear when the file is dragged.